# Select from another query result with additional joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query like this in SQL Server:

```
select * 
from 
    cargo as c, cargoshipment cs, 
    shipment s, shipmentbatch sb
where 
    c.id = cs.cargoid 
    and s.Id = sb.shipmentId  
    and sb.qty > 0 
    and c.arrivalDate != null
```

Now each table in the above query can contain several version for each record. Before selecting the above, i want each table to consider its latest version of a record.

For ex., in order to select recent version of a record in cargo table, I will have to join with another table like:

```
select * 
from cargo c 
join transaction t 
where c.txid = t.txid and status = 'latest'
```

The above query will ensure that cargo select a recent version of a record. I have to do the same for other three tables as well. Is it possible achieve it in single query?

Comment: If you have common field between cargo and shipment table then you can get your desired output in single query using join otherwise you may not I guess.

Comment: We need a little more information to go on, for example a join requires a matchable column value from each table. Please could you share the schema or the table-structure for these three tables so we can provide a full answer for you? Thanks

Comment: In addition to what @Simon asked, it would be useful to get some example data.

Comment: This `c.arrivalDate != null` should really be written as `c.arrivalDate IS NOT NULL` - you cannot apply the "normal" (in)equality operator to a `NULL`

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

according to the details you provided may be it goes like this:

```
select c.* from 
cargo c
join cargoshipment cs on c.id=cs.cargoid
join shipment s on c.Id=cs.cargoid
join shipmentbatch sb on sb.shipmentId=s.Id
join transaction t where c.txid=t.txid and status='latest'

where sb.qty > 0 and c.arrivalDate!=null
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Simon mentioned in his comment it's hard to answer without more information, but if I were to guess, you want something like the following:

```sql
select *
from cargo as c
inner join cargoshipment as cs on c.id = cs.cargoid
inner join shipment as s on s.Id = sb.shipmentId
inner join shipmentbatch sb
inner join transaction as c_t on c.txid = c_t.txid
inner join transaction as cs_t on c.txid = cs_t.txid
inner join transaction as s_t on c.txid = s_t.txid
inner join transaction as sb_t on c.txid = sb_t.txid
where sb.qty > 0
and c.arrivalDate is not null
and c_t.status = 'latest'
and cs_t.status = 'latest'
and s_t.status = 'latest'
and sb_t.status = 'latest';
```